# User class threw exception: java.util.MissingFormatWidthException: %-%

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark-sql, spark-shell

I am using Spark 2.4 and running below query,

```
select ID from WEB_TBL where ID NOT LIKE '%-%'
```

This query is giving proper output in Spark-shell but when I am running through Java class, its throwing below error.

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.util.MissingFormatWidthException: %-%
```

IS there something we need to do, while running spark-submit to execute this query. or can anyone suggest alternative for this query

Comment: Can you please post your complete code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the code, I tried locally with a java test case, working well for me-

```java
 @Test
    public void test62410606() {
        spark.sql("select ID from values ('1-1'), ('10') T(ID) where ID NOT LIKE '%-%'")
                .show(false);
        /**
         * +---+
         * |ID |
         * +---+
         * |10 |
         * +---+
         */
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what is the problem with my code, as I am able to see the results if I run the same query on spark-shell but some how it is failing if I am running through class and do spark-submit.